# How can I recover a plain text file encrypted by Veracrypt? I have the password

Tags: veracrypt

Encrypted the whole system drive with VeraCrypt, let it work **2 minutes** and defered. On reboot- partition information is gone, file format is RAW. No backup of the boot sector too.

Using file recovery software I was able to recover most documents, including plain text .txt. However: I had very important information stored in plain text (created with Notepad) files with changed extensions (so no one would assume they were text files.)

After recovery...all those files are gibberish...can't read in any Word or Notepad.

Is it possible to recover somehow using VeraCrypt? Is it an issue with file recovery software maybe? I tried several times - same result.

Comment: If the files were already encrypted, then it depends on whether the VeraCrypt headers are intact. If they are, it should be possible to recover them, though not easy, as I don't believe VeraCrypt has recovery tools. If the header is destroyed, then the master key is lost and there is no hope of recovering them. Either way, you may want to contact some recovery service. Doing this on your own may lead to more damage.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it, correct me if i'm wrong:
You started encrypting your system-drive.
let it work 2 min and you clicked defer, and rebooted?

Solution if this was correct:
just click continue encrypting it. And wait, until 100% done. Start the system, provide the password, and it should be okay.